# Contacts synchronisation

Tags: contacts, sync, gmail, exchange

I synchronized my Samsung S2 with mail Exchange account, and downloaded my contacts from Exchange server, but now I want to upload my contacts to my Gmail account. In my Gmail mail app I created new account but when I click sync my contact, nothing happens, no contact were uploaded to my Gmail acoount.

What to do ?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to sync your Exchange contacts to Gmail.  The easiest way is to do this on your computer.  This involves exporting your contacts from Outlook into a CSV file, and then importing that file on https://mail.google.com site.

1. Export your Outlook contacts to a CSV (Comma Separated Value) file.  Steps to do this vary for different Outlook versions, so search your Outlook's help for exact instructions pertaining to your particular version (e.g. Outlook 2010 instructions are [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/export-contacts-HA101870639.aspx).)
2. In your browser open Gmail, and navigate to "Contacts" section (click on the "Gmail" to reveal the drop-down.)
3. On the main Contacts screen click on `More` button and select the `Import...` option.
4. Click the "Browse" button in the "Choose FIle to Upload" window, and navigate to the folder where you saved the CSV file from step 1.
5. Click the "Open" button, then select the "Import Contacts", and the contents of the CSV file should import to your Gmail account.
6. Either wait a bit, or manually force a sync via `Settings -> Accounts & sync` screen on your phone.